# How to write on connecting lines in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-trees

So I am trying to do a similar diagram:

[image]

I have done this so far:

```
 \documentclass{article} 
 \usepackage{tikz}

 \begin{document} 
 \begin{tikzpicture}


   % Circles   
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) node[circle,minimum
 size=1cm,draw,fill] (A) {$H$};   
\draw[fill=white] (-4,-5)
 node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (B) {$\sigma$};  
 \draw[fill=white] (4,-5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (C)
 {$T$};   
\draw[fill=white] (0,-1.5) node[circle,minimum
 size=1cm,draw,fill] (D) {$M$};   
\draw[fill=white] (-1.3,-3.5)
 node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (E) {$\varepsilon$};  
 \draw[fill=white] (1.3,-3.5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill]
 (F) {$\delta S$};


   % Paths   
\draw[-] (A) -- (B);   
\draw[-] (A) -- (C);   
\draw[-] (A)-- (D);   
\draw[-] (A) -- (D);   
\draw[-] (D) -- (E);   
\draw[-] (D) -- (F);   
\draw[-] (E) -- (F);   
\draw[-] (D) -- (B);   
\draw[-] (D) -- (C);   
\draw[-] (E) -- (B);    
\draw[-] (E) -- (C);      
\draw[-] (F) -- (C);     
\draw[-] (F) -- (B);     
\draw[-] (B) -- (C);    
 \end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

[image]

- **How can I write stuff on the lines as in the first picture?**
- **Is the method I am using the most efficient?** *Notice that changing any of the circles sizes/nodes positions will make the lines intersect, circles with different sizes (some small, some large, depending on the text inside), etc...*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write

```
\draw (D) -- (C) node[midway, font=\scriptsize, sloped] {<text>};
```

You can add `above` or `below` to the options to change the position.

If you need to "move" the node along the path, then replace `midway` with `pos=` and give a number between 0 and 1 after the `=`, so that `0` is the starting point of the path, `1` is the end, and each decimal is a point. For example, `pos=0.5` is equivalent to `midway`, `pos=.75` is 3/4 of the path, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an `edge` to draw a line, then you can load the `quotes` library and say, for example,

```
\draw (A) edge ["text along line"] (B);
```

If you use the `auto` option when configuring the `every edge quotes` style, then you can write `"text along line"'` to 'swap' the relation of the label to the path e.g. from above to below or from left to right.

For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every edge quotes/.append style={sloped, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, auto}
  ]
 % Circles
 \draw[fill=white] (0,0) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (A) {$H$};
 \draw[fill=white] (-4,-5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (B) {$\sigma$};
 \draw[fill=white] (4,-5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (C) {$T$};
 \draw[fill=white] (0,-1.5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (D) {$M$};
 \draw[fill=white] (-1.3,-3.5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (E) {$\varepsilon$};
 \draw[fill=white] (1.3,-3.5) node[circle,minimum size=1cm,draw,fill] (F) {$\delta S$};
 % Paths
 \draw (A) edge ["Something here"'] (B);
 \draw (A) -- (C);
 \draw (A) -- (D);
 \draw (A) -- (D);
 \draw (D) -- (E);
 \draw (D) -- (F);
 \draw (E) -- (F);
 \draw (D) -- (B);
 \draw (D) -- (C);
 \draw (E) -- (B);
 \draw (E) -- (C);
 \draw (F) -- (C);
 \draw (F) -- (B);
 \draw (B) edge ["Something else"'] (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: edge quotes for labels]